# How would you model a table to record changes in other tables' records' values?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, activerecord, schema

I am writing a model to record the changes that are made to other models so that there is a record of every attribute change. I'm looking for input on how best to structure the change record table.

For instance, I have a `User` model with a `name` attribute. I want to save a `Change` record to the database when that user has its name changed from `Bob` to `Ted`.

Furthermore, if a user updates multiple attributes on the `User` at the same time I would like to record these as being a single `Change`. For instance, a `User` changes both the `name` and `email` attributes from `Bob` and `bob@bobsdomain.com` to `Ted` and `ted@teddy.com`, respectively.

The set of attributes on a given object that are being changed are arbitrary. How would you structure the table?

Currently, I am doing something like the following (simplified):

```
Changes:
  user_id:integer
  changed_fields:string
  old_values:text
  new_values:text
```

In the above examples these records would look like the following:

```
:changed_fields => "name", 
:old_values => "Bob", 
:new_values => "Ted"
```

and

```
:changed_fields => "name,email", 
:old_values => "Bob,bob@bobsdomain.com", 
:new_values => "Ted,ted@teddy.com"
```

On the `Change` model I have special getter/setter methods that parse the input/output to map to specific formatting.

**Is there a better way to model this kind of thing?**

If not, what is the best way to format the values for the database to make parsing the input/output work best, given that the values can be arbitrary.

I am using Postgres as my DB and ActiveRecord as the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing both the old and new value is redundant. You could instead store just the new value at the time of the change, and make sure you also add a change record when a new row is created. If a row has been changed N times, it will have N+1 records in the change table, and you can find the differences between them retrospectively if you need to.

In fact, one approach is to have only one table containing all versions of the data. Instead of updating any rows in-place, make edits by inserting new rows. I've taken this approach while either using a boolean "latest" field, or using a foreign key from another table, to refer to the current version of each row.

These days though I'm using the django-reversion package to implement revision tracking for me. It uses a single table to record all versions of all tracked tables, storing a JSON representation of the state of each object at each version. It uses an additional table to track whole change-sets, so it can version changes that span multiple objects.

The solution that's best for you will depend on which operations you need to be able to do efficiently on your tables, and on what your ORM makes easy for you to work with. I hope this answer has been helpful at pointing out some approaches that have worked in other settings.

Comment: Thanks Jamey. That is actually very useful. I had not thought about the fact that the old values are redundant. I think I will probably take that approach as it doesn't require me modifying how AR expects to find models.